# Wordpress page title not shown on certain pages

Tags: wordpress, menu, page-title

For some reason page titles are not shown on SOME of my pages above the content in Wordpress.

I use a drop-down menu, and *only* the pages in that drop-down menu do not show page-titles - the other pages are okay. The pages that don't show titles are not child-pages of another page.

Page that DOES work: http://www.20watt.nl/informatie/

Page that does NOT work:  http://www.20watt.nl/bruiloft/  (comes under the above page in the dropdownmenu)

Any help is welcome & thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several things depending on your theme . 
But one thing is that you are not using the same page templates on those pages 
One is  `page-template-templatesfullwidth-php` and the other is `page-template-default` in which you also have double headers ..

Comment: Fantastic! That fixed it :) I'll have to make sure that all my ages use the same template. Thanks!

Comment: @20Watt - yes. but now your page is toooo wide . :-) but that´s for another question ..

Comment: Haha, I noticed that too - I took a look at both template files and noticed the H1 header (the culprit!)  was missing from the default template, so took it from the full-width template. All good now!